# redux-form doesn't get submitted

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a strange bug in my app. I want to let the user update the name of a group via redux form. Exchanging the old name with the input field works without problem, but when I click on Submit, then nothing happens. This is very strange for me, because I am using the same form to create the group in the first place and there it works totally fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import { deleteAccessGroup, editAccessGroup } from '../actions/UserActions';
import { showModal } from '../actions/ModalActions';
import * as types from '../actions/index';
import AccessGroupCreation from '../components/AccessGroupCreation';

class AccessGroupElement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toggle: false
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = values => {
    this.props.editAccessGroup(values);
    console.log(this.state, "Das sind die values: ", values);
    this.edit;
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  edit = () => this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle});

  delAccessGroup = () => this.props.deleteAccessGroup(this.props.accessGroup.id);

  showPicModal = () => {
    let id = this.props.accessGroup.id;

    this.props.showModal(types.MODAL_TYPE_PICUPLOAD, {
      title: 'Please upload a Profile Picture',
      onConfirm: (pic) => {
        console.log(this.props.accessGroup.id);
        console.log( pic)
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const accessGroup=this.props.accessGroup;

    return(
      <div className="row" id="hoverDiv">
        <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
        {this.state.toggle ?
        <div className="col-lg-9">
          <AccessGroupCreation onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        </div> :
        <div className="col-lg-9">{accessGroup.name}</div>}
        <div className="col-lg-2">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.delAccessGroup}
                  className="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.edit}
                  className="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { deleteAccessGroup, editAccessGroup, showModal })(AccessGroupElement);
```

Here is the form component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required';

const lengthFunction = (min, max) => value =>
  value && (value.length > max || value.length < min) ? `Must be between ${min} and ${max} characters` : undefined

const length = lengthFunction(5, 20);

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control"/>
      {touched && (error && <span>{error}</span>)}
  </div>
);

const AccessGroupCreation = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = props;

  return (
    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input-group">
      <Field name="name" type="text"
             component={renderField} label="Add an Access Group"
             validate={[ required, length]}/>

             <span className="input-group-btn">
               <button className="btn btn-success" disabled={pristine || submitting}
                       value="this.state.value" type="submit">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                  Submit
               </button>
             </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'AccessGroupCreationForm' // a unique identifier for this form
})(AccessGroupCreation)
```

Help, as always, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this code:

```
handleSubmit = values => {
  this.props.editAccessGroup(values);
  console.log(this.state, "Das sind die values: ", values);

  this.edit;  // call this function this.edit();

  console.log(this.state);
}
```

Comment: Well, I changed the call to this.edit(), but it still doesn't work. The issue seems that the action never gets fired, because the two console logs I entered into the function never appear in my console. Which makes sense, as I can't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `editAccessGroup` function isn't tied to your store. Right now, it's creating and returning an action, but that action isn't being dispatched.

The way I'd usually implement it is to use `react-redux`'s `connect` function and use `mapDispatchToProps` to bind the actionCreator to your store's `dispatch` function.

Comment: I used the shorthand version to hook it up. My connect function looks like this:
```
export default connect(null, { deleteAccessGroup, editAccessGroup, showModal })(AccessGroupElement);
```

Normally I would say that the error could be the missing mapDispatchToProps function, but my deleteAccessGroup function works, and it is hooked up the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Change few thing as-

```
     ...

class AccessGroupElement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      ...
  }

  submit = values => { // rename this function
    this.props.editAccessGroup(values);
    console.log(this.state, "Das sind die values: ", values);
    this.edit;
    console.log(this.state);
  }

     ....

  render() {
    const accessGroup=this.props.accessGroup;

    return(
      <div className="row" id="hoverDiv">
          ........
        <div className="col-lg-9">
          <AccessGroupCreation submit={this.submit} /> // change here
        </div> :
          .........
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { deleteAccessGroup, editAccessGroup, showModal })(AccessGroupElement);
```

**then on your form-**

```
const AccessGroupCreation = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, submit } = props; // getting submit function

  return (
    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
         .......
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'AccessGroupCreationForm' // a unique identifier for this form
})(AccessGroupCreation)
```

Comment: I applied all the changes you suggested, but it unfortunately still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was the use of react-collapsible. It seems like the event handlers "clash", when having redux-form inside/replacing a collapsible. I changed the code and now it works:

```
  <div className="row" id="hoverDiv" key={ accessGroup.id }>
        <div className="col-lg-1"/>
          {
            this.state.toggle ?
              <div className="col-lg-9">
                <AccessGroupEdit onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
              </div> :
              <div className="col-lg-9">
                <Collapsible trigger={accessGroup.name}>
                  <small><i>Apps:</i></small>
                    <ul className="list-inline">
                      {accessGroup.apps.map(group => {
                        return <li key={group.id}><img width="75px"
                                                       height="50px"
                                                       src={group.image}
                                                       alt={group.name} />
                               </li>})}
                    </ul>
                  <hr />
                  <small><i>Permissions:</i></small>
                    <ul className="list-inline">
                      {Object.keys(accessGroup.permissions).map(permission => {
                        return accessGroup.permissions[permission] ?
                        <li key={permission}>
                          <span className="label label-primary">{permission}</span>
                        </li> : ""
                      })}
                    </ul>
                </Collapsible>
              </div>
          }
        <div className="col-lg-2">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.delAccessGroup}
                  className="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.edit}
                  className="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```